# MariaDB Slave Error - String is too long for MASTER_HOST

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, database-replication, mariadb

I'm attempting to replicate an AWS RDS instance with MariaDB. For those not familiar, RDS instances have extremely long DNS hostnames and cannot be accessed by their underlying IP address.

When it comes time to issue the "change master" command, I receive the following error:

> String
>   'my rds dns name' is
>   too long for MASTER_HOST (should be no longer than 60)

I can't figure out how to bypass this.  Any ideas?

*For the record, I have successfully done this before with non RDS machines.  I'm not a complete noob :)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a DNS `CNAME` record in one of your  domains, with the long fqdn of the RDS instance as its target.

Then, reference the RDS in your replication config by the new, shorter hostname.

This is actually a good idea for another reason -- if you ever change the RDS instance where your data lives, you only have to update one thing -- the cname entry.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.  Just feels like a hack for a simple problem

Comment: I'd suggest that it's actually a very valid use of a `CNAME` record.  I do this in my systems, not because of name length constraints, but to remove the need to reconfigure multiple entities in the event something changes with RDS... as well as because the short name is easier to remember, heh.